# How to enable picture appear when a link is shared on WhatsApp?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

[image]

How to enable images to be shown when a link is shared in whatsapp? Like the link above from amprandom.blogspot.com.

OG tags modified as needed. Still does not show images. How to get it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to see the information that is used when your website content is shared on Facebook, Messenger and other places. The Batch Invalidator will let you refresh this information for multiple URLs at the same time. Open Graph markup lets you take control over how your website content appears to others.

> Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Steps:

1. Add needed `og tags` ex. `og:title`, `og:image`, etc in your website code.
2. After adding necessary tags, go to [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and enter your website URL there.
3. Click on Debug. It will show all the data scrapped by it and refreshes them.

Next time you share your website/link, it will scrap metadata added to it.

**Edit:** 
You need to add `itemprop` to the `og:image` meta-tag

Ex: change value of url_image to your image/ logo/ favicon url.

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="url_image">
```

Thumbnail schema from schema.org inside  for WhatsApp

```
<link itemprop="thumbnailUrl" href="url_image"> 
<span itemprop="thumbnail" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"> 
  <link itemprop="url" href="url_image"> 
</span>
```

Comment: Facebook share works fine. That's the WhatsApp share I am worried about.

Comment: I tried that worked. I thought I should update on where I went wrong. The image size had to be less than 300KB.